# Displaying a component in EditorGridPanel without clicking

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is there a way to display a component in EditorGridPanel without the need to click on the cell?

The problem I see on this [demo](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/edit-grid.html) is that the checkboxes are not Ext.form.Checkbox components, and not even inherited from it. The checkboxes are simply background images and since I am building a grid that needs ComboBoxes, it will not be simple to apply a similar hack.

Comment: What demo are you referring to?

What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want a grid that displays editable comboboxes on every row, when the grid is initially rendered? (Or is your problem related to checkboxes or comboboxes?)

Comment: Oh, sorry. I updated my post to contain the demo link. What I want is to show a combobox component in one column (per each row). The EditorGridPanel works fine except that it will display the component only when I click on the field that contains it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I see what you're after now. Immediately display the combobox on each row upon grid rendering. That might be difficult to achieve, and I suspect it might have a negative effect on the overall performance of the grid (multiple comboboxes to render instead of just one).

In any case, have you looked at the `clicksToEdit` config option of `EditorGridPanel`? From ExtJS documentation:

> The number of clicks on a cell
>   required to display the cell's editor
>   (defaults to 2).
>
> Setting this option to 'auto' means
>   that mousedown on the selected cell
>   starts editing that cell.

How about if you tried setting this to **'auto'**? That would at least reduce the amount of mouseclicks that the user has to do, before editing starts. Is that what you're really after with this?

(Note that I haven't tried this option myself, so I don't know how well it actually works with Comboboxes.)

Comment: Yes the option works, but the thing is that I want to show that there is a combobox, because it looks ridiculous that it suddenly appears after mousedown/click. My client wants that and I need to accomplish it somehow. Textboxes make more sense when they operate that way, but comboboxes are just silly when they are rendered prior  to clicks. And oh, there are only 10 comboboxes shown at the same time, I can take the performance "hit".